# Javascript - event listener not working

Tags: javascript

I am using zurb foundation and their button for uploading file which hides the name of the uploaded file. I would like to show it, so I used the suggested solution [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/50259-adding-filename-feedback-to-stylized-foundation-file-upload-buttons):

```js
(function() {

  // Attach the change event listener to change the label of input[type=file] element
  var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
  console.log(input);

  input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var label = this.previousElementSibling;
    console.log(label);
    label.innerHTML = this.files[0].name;
  });

})();
```

```html
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> Hent fil (CSV format): <br>
  <label for="csvFile" class="button">Upload File</label>
  <input type="file" id="csvFile" name="csvFile" class="show-for-sr">
  <p><input type="submit" class="hollow button" value="Last opp" /></p>
</form>
```

This is the created html in browser:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="http://admin/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="MeCNU58hUdEfsi8SmfP9OGlmW0wpb1WGeC9jEJGe">
   Hent fil (CSV format): <br> 
  <label for="csvFile" class="button">Upload File</label> 
  <input type="file" id="csvFile" name="csvFile" class="show-for-sr">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Last opp" class="hollow button"></p>
</form>
```

On page load I get in the console input field for `console.log(input);` but on uploading file nothing happens, I don't get anything in the console for `console.log(label)`.

My project is built with Laravel framework. I am having one main script on the page:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

In that script I am requiring all other scripts, which is now only the script shown above and a bootstrap script:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
require('./bootstrap');
require('./fileUpload');
/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

bootstrap.js looks like this:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap-sass');

/**
 * Vue is a modern JavaScript library for building interactive web interfaces
 * using reactive data binding and reusable components. Vue's API is clean
 * and simple, leaving you to focus on building your next great project.
 */

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: 'your-pusher-key'
// });
```

It seems to work when I am not using the foundation classes for upload button, when it is just the default upload button:

```
<input type="file" id="csvFile" name="csvFile" class="button"><br>
```

Not sure, what from foundation is blocking it?

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. The HTML is missing from your question.

Comment: Your code works without any problems when I test it.

Comment: Yes, It works without any issue. https://jsfiddle.net/8jo6qfs1/1/

Comment: Yes, I have no idea, why it won't work on my machine locally

Comment: you're outputting the rendered markup, right? and not the `view source` ?

Comment: @xandercoded it looks the same

Comment: copy/pasta it into the post. at the time the event is triggered (set breakpoint).

Comment: just reproduced the desired behavior with your generated markup, no cigar; still seeing the console output. something else, non-standard/funky, is happening ... godspeed. do update this post with more information or the cause when you find it. may help out someone else in the future ...

Comment: it seems to not work only when I am using zurb foundation solution for hidding the default upload button, when I am using default upload button, it is working as it should